# how to get list of SSL certificates attached to ELB in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I have tried using this command , I want to get the list of SSL certifiates attached to a load balancer.

```
aws elbv2 describe-ssl-policies
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `describe-listener-certificates` instead. Please refer [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/describe-listener-certificates.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command:

```
aws elbv2 describe-listener-certificates --listener-arn **arn_of_listener**
```

Replace the arn_of_listener with your own ARN of the listener.

Hope it helps.